Bitbucket custom image with shared data
Please bare with me as I am fairly new to DevOps as a whole.
I am trying to create a custom image for bitbucket to use. This image has maven installed to it and configures ~/.m2/settings.xml so that it can be used globally throughout the pipeline steps.
Docker Image:
FROM maven:3.9-eclipse-temurin-19-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache wget net-tools

RUN mkdir -p /root/.m2 && chmod -R 777 /root/.m2 && touch /root/.m2/settings.xml
ENV MAVEN_CONFIG="/root/.m2"

WORKDIR /opt/atlassian/bitbucketci/agent/build

RUN ls -lah /root/.m2 && (cat /root/.m2/settings.xml || echo "none")

CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]

As you can see I created a .m2 directory with a testing settings.xml and I was trying to debug and see if it is being created or not. I also added net-tools on purpose just to see if it will be available through the steps also.
image: 
  name: <docker username>/<custom image>:1
  username: $DOCKER_USERNAME
  password: $DOCKER_PASSWORD

pipelines:
  default:
  - step:
      name: "Pull bash script"
      script:
        - ls . && echo "This is cwd"
        - echo $MAVEN_HOME
        - telnet
        - ls ~/.m2 | echo "no m2"
        - ls /usr/share/maven | echo "nothing in usr"

This is the pipeline that i have been testing on. My question is, how can I access the created ~/.m2 directory in the image? I feel like everything that I install there is not being shared with the rest of the pipelines.

Have you tried /root/.m2? What does the pipeline return with those steps?
